# O que devo usar pra fazer um sistema de grid dentro de outro?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou fazendo um carousel que mostrará alguns anúncios de posts postados recentemente. A `div` que contém o carousel é um `container`, e os elementos do carousel também são do tipo `container`. Quando eu for criar grids dentro de outros elementos que já fazem parte de outra grid o que eu devo fazer? Devo começar com o `container` e seguir com `row` e `col` ou eu devo fazer de outra maneira?

Exemplo:
[image: exemplo]

Elemento do carousel:

[image: elemento do carousel]

Comment: Essas linhas cinza dentro do box amarelo eh apenas simulando o que seria um texto ou vc realmente precisa que elas sejam uma div ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Para o Boostrap 4**

Eu NÃO recomendo que vc use um `container` dentro do outro. Até pq não precisa disso para fazer esse "aninhamento" com o Grid, como vc pode consultar direto na documentação oficial sobre `Nesting Grid` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting

Veja que apenas `COL-*` pode ser filho direto de `ROW`

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Para dar os espaçamento vc deve usar as classes nativas do BS4 como `p` ou `m` para `margin` e `padding` Aqui tem a documentação oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que vc não precisa de CSS além do original do BS4, a única coisa que fiz com CSS foi colocar as cores de fundo. Veja o código referente a imagem acima:

```css
.container {
    background-color: purple;
}
.row {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.col-3 {
    background-color: tomato;
}
.col-9 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.col-12 {
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row p-4">
        <div class="col-3 p-4">
            col-3
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 p-4">
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">col-12</div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">col-12</div>
            <div class="col-12">col-12</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

***Se vc ainda estiver usando Bootstrap 3 veja que:***

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, **neither container is nestable**.

PORTUGUÊS
*"O Bootstrap requer um elemento que contenha conteúdo do site e hospede nosso sistema de grid. Você pode escolher um dos dois contêineres para usar em seus projetos. Observe que, devido ao preenchimento e mais, **nenhum `container` é aninhado.**"*

**Outro ponto: `Row > Container`** (isso é errado!)

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of `rows`.

PORTUGUÊS
*"O conteúdo deve ser colocado dentro de colunas e somente colunas podem ser filhos imediatos de `rows`."*

**Ouse seja, apenas `COL-*` pode ser filho direto de uma `ROW`**

*Fonte da documentação oficial:* https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: se colocar uma row como pai das tres colunas col-12 mas que seja filho da col-9,  seria ruim?

Comment: @RenanOsorio não sei se entendi direito... Mas uma Row pode ser filho direto de uma Col-, assim como uma Col- deve ser filho de uma Row, o que não é aconselhável é .Container dentro de Row ou Col. Tirando isso vc pode "aninhar" a vontade Rows e Cols

Comment: bom saber, obrigado.

Comment: @RenanOsorio veja que quando vc tem um col-12 ela automaricamente vai ocupar tudo o espaço horizontal, e o próximo elemento que vier depois dela vai automaticamente "cair" para a linha de baixo. Visto isso vc não precisa separar col-12 uma em cada Row, assim como vc não precisa separar qualquer soma que complete 12, tipo col-3 + col-9 = 12, então vc poderia ter depois dessas duas col- mais uma col- que automaticamente ela "cairia" para a linha de baixo entende

Comment: Resumindo vc não precisa necessariamente separar um grupo de 12 por row, pois a cada 12 a row já quebra, tipo 4 col-6 ficaria direitinho um gride de 4 elementos 2 por linha sem precisar de uma row separando duas col-6 das outras duas col-6

Comment: na vdd eu estava me referindo a isso https://jsfiddle.net/n9x4zLyd/

Comment: @RenanOsorio agora entendi. Cara vc não necessariamente precisa colocar um Row ali. Se vc colocar o grid não vai ficar legal pq ele vai "anular" o espaçamento natural das Row. Uma Col pode ser filha de Outra, mas dependendo da "distribuição" das celulas do seu layout vc pode precisar de uma Row extra dentro de alguma Col para fazer o conteúdo quebrar para linha de baixo, nesse caso pode ser que vc precise de padding ou margin para corrigir qq detalhe. Vai um pouco de cada caso. A melhor maneira de aprender é testando, crie um arquivo com esse "grid" ai e vai brincando e vendo como ele reage

Answer (score -1):

É necessario o container ja que se nao perde o margin do container e fica pegado a os laterales. Exemplo com o container:

```css
.roww {
  height: 20px;
  min-height:20px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.image {
  background-color: orange;
}

.rows {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 image">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 rows">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row roww">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row roww">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row roww">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo sem o container:

```css
.roww {
  height: 20px;
  min-height:20px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.image {
  background-color: orange;
}

.rows {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 image">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 rows">
        <div class="row roww">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row roww">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row roww">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```